# Python PuLP "if" complies only with first condition.

Tags: python, if-statement, pulp

I am trying to use PuLP to optimize a system, minimizing the cost of it. I am using multiple If's and the problem is that it always meets the first condition. Here is my code. I hope someone can help me, as I am just starting to learn about this language.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pulp import *

idx = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
d = {
'day': pd.Series(['01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14'], index=idx),
'hour':pd.Series(['00:00:00', '01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00', '05:00:00', '06:00:00', '07:00:00', '08:00:00', '09:00:00', '10:00:00', '11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00', '14:00:00', '15:00:00', '16:00:00', '17:00:00', '18:00:00', '19:00:00', '20:00:00', '21:00:00', '22:00:00', '23:00:00'], index=idx),
'output':pd.Series([0,0,0,0.087,0.309,0.552,0.682,0.757,0.783,0.771,0.715,0.616,0.466,0.255,0.022,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], index=idx)}
cfPV = pd.DataFrame(d)


idx = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
d1 = {
'day': pd.Series(['01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14', '01/01/14'], index=idx),
'hour':pd.Series(['00:00:00', '01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00', '05:00:00', '06:00:00', '07:00:00', '08:00:00', '09:00:00', '10:00:00', '11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00', '14:00:00', '15:00:00', '16:00:00', '17:00:00', '18:00:00', '19:00:00', '20:00:00', '21:00:00', '22:00:00', '23:00:00'], index=idx),
'output':pd.Series([0.528,0.512,0.51,0.448,0.62,0.649,0.601,0.564,0.541,0.515,0.502,0.522,0.57,0.638,0.66,0.629,0.589,0.544,0.506,0.471,0.448,0.438,0.443,0.451], index=idx)}
cfWT = pd.DataFrame(d1)


prob = LpProblem ("System", LpMinimize)

CPV = LpVariable ("PVCapacity",0) #PV Capacity in kW
CWT = LpVariable ("WTurCapacity",0) #WT Capacity in kW
CBA = LpVariable ("BatteryCapacity",0) #Battery Capacity kW

prob+= 63.128*CPV + 88.167*CWT + 200*CBA, "TotalCostSystem"

xEne = 0
xREin = 0
xBin = 0
xBout = 0
SOCB = 0
xPEMin = 0
xOvEn = 0
xSum = 0

CPEM = 230

for i in idx:

    xEne = (CPV*cfPV['output'][i]+CWT*cfWT['output'][i])

    #Low limit for Variables
    prob += (CPV*cfPV['output'][i]+CWT*cfWT['output'][i]) >= 0
    prob += xREin >= 0
    prob += xBin >= 0
    prob += xBout >= 0
    prob += SOCB >= 0
    prob += xPEMin >= 0
    prob += xOvEn >= 0
    prob += xSum >= 0
    prob += CBA >= SOCB
    prob += xBin <= (CBA - SOCB)
    prob += xBout <= SOCB

    #Cases

    #Case 1 xEne > CPEM
    if xEne >= CPEM:

        xREin = CPEM
        xBout = 0
        xOvEn = xEne - CPEM 

        #Case 1.1 xOvEn < CBA - SOCB
        if (value(xOvEn) <= (CBA - value(SOCB))): 
            xBin = xOvEn

        #Case 1.2 xOvEn > CBA -SOCB
        else: 
            xBin = CBA - SOCB 

    #Case 2 xEne < CPEM
    else:
        xREin = xEne
        xBin = 0 
        xOvEn = 0

        #Case 2.1 SOCB > CPEM - xREin
        if (value(SOCB) >= (CPEM - value(xREin))):
            xBout = (CPEM - xREin)

        #Case 2.2 SOCB < CPEM - xREin 
        else:

            xBout = SOCB 

    SOCB = SOCB + xBin - xBout
    xPEMin = xREin + xBout 

    xSum += xPEMin

prob += xSum >= 5000


prob.writeLP("PVWTBattSyste.lp")

prob.solve()
```

The solution given always meets first condition. Also, when the condition is not met (changing CPEM to 50000000000000, for example) the if works as it is true.

I have the same result using "elif". And if I change the order of the conditions (meaning the firs if as xEne <= CPEM, the result change to only comply with the first new condition.

Thank you in advance!

Priscila Castillo

Answer (score 2):

The if statement doesn't work because the variables don't have defined values until after optimisation.

Think in the lp problem you set up relationship between the LpVariables and the optimiser finds a solution that matches it.

In your case you are mixing LpVariables and python integers in a way which is incorrect.

Perhaps look at 
http://www.yzuda.org/Useful_Links/optimization/if-then-else-02.html

or

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-053-optimization-methods-in-management-science-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_053S13_lec11.pdf

or

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.464.6182&rep=rep1&type=pdf

for help

Stu